# Get current HTML element in PHP

Tags: php

I may have misunderstood the purpose of PHP here. But I want to do the following:

I have a PHP function, and I call it from HTML, e.g.

```
  <BODY>
    <DIV id='A'>
      <?php emit("hello1"); ?>
    </DIV>
    <DIV id='B'>
      <?php emit("hello2"); ?>
    </DIV>
  </BODY>
```

And I want to know, within the function, which `DIV` it was called from.
e.g.

```
  <?php function emit($txt){
           echo "$txt";
           echo "from DIV id $DIVID"
        } 
  ?>
```

And I want it, obviously, to print

```
hello1 from DIV id A
hello2 from DIV id B
```

Is there any way of finding the "current" DIV's ID?

Comment: that would require an HTML / XML parser in PHP. that is very dirty business and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have misunderstood the purpose of PHP.

PHP is a server side programming language, it does not run on the HTML page, but before the HTML gets loaded on to the browser.

The task that you are trying to do can be done from JavaScript if interested. I will give an *example* of jQuery:

```
var emit = function(el, txt) {
    var id = el.attr('id');
    el.html(txt+" from DIV id "+id);

}
```

Now call using

```
emit($("#a"), "hello1");
```

Same can be done from JS in the following way

```
var emit = function(el, txt) {
    el = document.getElementById("el");    
    id = el.getAttribute('id');
    el.innerHTML(txt+" from DIV id "+id);
};
```

Use like:

```
emit("a", "hello1");
```

Comment: Perfect, I'm using jQuery anyway, so this will do the job.

Comment: @SanjayManohar, It should fire an event to trigger the function call. What do you exactly want? my above example, give you the above output.